# Python: How to select all other items in a for loop

Tags: python, recursion

Let's say I have:

```
def recursive(data):
    for i in data:
        if condition:
            recursive(HERE IS THE ISSUE)
```

How do I pass in the data from the current `i` to the final element in the list?

Comment: What is i? Is it a class? then maybe `i.data`? Where is the `data` in the `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) this will also return the current loop index which you can then slice with.

```
def recursive(data):
   for i,j in enumerate(data):
      if condition:
         recursive(data[i:])
```

Comment: @glglgl Yes you are correct. I guess I assumed it from "current i to the final element in the list". Lists are sliceable.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you iterated based on index:

```
def recursive(data):
  for i in range(len(data)):
    if condition:
      recursive(data[i:])
```